# Restore application from system tray

Tags: c#, winapi, process

What is the best way to programmatically restore and give focus to a third-party application (say, GoogleTalk or Twhirl) running in the system tray? I am writing my utility in C#, but I obviously have no control over the third-party application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like FindWindow /[FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx) to find the hidden window and get its window handle and then call [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(VS.85).aspx) ( handle, SW_NORMAL) to unhide it.

Use a tool like Spy++ (can be found in the visual studio tools menu) to find the parameters which can be passed on to FindWindow to locate the desired window.

Comment: What if the hidden window has a Handle=0?

Comment: AFAIK a NULL handle represents an invalid HANDLE...FindWindow returns NULL when it fails in finding the specified window.

Answer (score 0):

Use an API call to send mouse click events to the system tray?  Google WM_SENDMSG SendMessage Win32 API for a starting point

There's also another [API call](http://www.xmlauthor.com/help/Extensions/WindowsAPI/SetFocus.htm) for setting focus once the window's back up.